# Are all city names ending in CESTER pronounced as STER?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, proper-nouns, names

I have heard all the names of English city names ending in CESTER pronounced as STER but I wonder if it is a "rule" and I should pronounce all of them as STER? Gloucester, Leicester, and Towcester all have STER.

Comment: English place names can be very difficult to pronounce, and locals sometimes use a different version. From the question, you have **Gloster**, **Lester** and **Toaster**. Then there is Wymondham which is said as **Windum**, etc.

Comment: English place names, as @Weather Vane said, can be difficult to pronounce. See for instance **Quernmore** (*kwor-muh*), **Beaulieu** (*bew-lee*), **Woolfardisworthy** (*wul-zry*) and my fav one — **Rampisham** pronounced (Drumroll, please) ..... ***Ran-som***.

Comment: And of course there's **Worcester** (pronounced "wooster").

Comment: And many have the same odd pronunciationes in the US (and Canada, Australia etc), like "Worcester", which is pronounced roughly the same way when it comes to the names of the US cities with the same name (give or take rhoticity).  But some are pronounced differently in the US, e.g. "Birmingham", "Derby".  Interestingly, "Hertford" is pronounced the same but spelt differently ("Hartford" in the US - at least in Connecticut - there is a Hertford in N Carolina and I don't know how it's pronounced).

Comment: Questions using terms such as *all* are generally unaswerarable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English place names can be difficult to pronounce.

#### Names ending in *-cester*

Almost all *-cester*'s are pronounced **/stə(r)/** (*ste(r)*):

- Alcester → /ˈɒlstə/ or /ˈɔːlstə/
- Gloucester → /ˈɡlɒstə(r)/
- Worcester → /ˈwʊstə(r)/
- Bicester → /ˈbɪstə(r)/
- Towcester → /ˈtəʊstə(r)/
- Leicester → /ˈlestə(r)/

**Exception:**
The only exception I can think of is **Cirencester**, where the *-cester* is pronounced /-sestə/ (*cester*): /ˈsaɪrənsestə(r)/

Other weird names are:

- Woolfardisworthy → /ˈwʊlzri/
- Quernmore → /ˈkwɔːmə(r)/
- Rampisham → /ˈrænsəm/
- Cholmondeley → /ˈt͡ʃʌmli/
- Beaulieu → /ˈbjuli/
- Omagh → /ˈəʊmɑː/

You'll have to learn every name by rote.

Comment: How is /sestə/ supposed to be pronounced please?

Comment: @Visitor: It's pronounced *cester*, I edited my answer.

Comment: And other names ending in "Cester"? All are pronounced STER?

Comment: @Visitor: Yes, almost all of them are pronounced *ster*. I can't think of any other exception.

Comment: Locals often call Cirencester "Sisister" but this has been dying out since 1950 approx.

Comment: The schwa (ə) shouldn't be written as *er* honestly, there are very few rhotic accents in the UK - the majority of people pronounce *-er* as the schwa, more like *uh*

Comment: Did an American tourist going to Loughborough really ask a railway ticket clerk for a ticket to 'Looga-Burooga'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey when my father was a railway ticket clerk the stock reply to "Two to Looe" would be "Pip pip".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey no idea about American tourists but a few years ago one of the guards on EMR regularly announced our arrival at Loogerburooger

Comment: I was told that the porters at Waterloo used to shout "Woddybridge" for Wadebridge (in Cornwall) because, if they didn't, people misheard it as Weybridge and got carried a long way on the Atlantic Coast Express (first stop Salisbury) before they could double back.

Comment: There's a [list of -cesters, -chesters, etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chester_(placename_element)) on Wikipedia which confirms this, saying Cirencester is the only exception.